# print dataframe to be used in markdownhere

Tags: python, pandas, markdown

I would like to print dataframe to markdown and use it in markdownhere.

I saw to_markdown() api but the format not work in markdownhere.

So I try below code, it works fine:

```
import pandas as pd

def dumpmd(df):
    out = []
    out.append("|".join(df.columns))
    r = []
    for name in df.columns:
        r.append(":-")
    out.append("|".join(r))    
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        r = []
        r1 = []
        for e in row:
            r.append(str(e))
        out.append("|".join(r))
    out = "\n".join(out)
    return out


data = [['1','B','C'],
    ['2','E','F'],
    ['3','H','I']]


df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["C1" ,"C2","C3"])

print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt='pipe',index=False))
print(dumpmd(df))
```

Output:

```
| C1 | C2 | C3 |
|----+----+----|
|  1 | B  | C  |
|  2 | E  | F  |
|  3 | H  | I  |
C1|C2|C3
:-|:-|:-
1|B|C
2|E|F
3|H|I
```

Would anyone help simplify this code or any better solution to output expected markdown table from dataframe?

Comment: In what way does the format not work in markdownhere? it should do...

Comment: You mentioned `to_markdown`, but when I tried with `to_markdown(index=False)` and pasted the markdown table on the https://markdown-here.com/, it renders as [this](https://i.imgur.com/q08QQLE.png)

Comment: In my case, the to_markdown has + instead of |, |-------+-------+-------|, Does that depends on text contents?

Comment: Just found if fist column is number, then the connector will changed to +, but why....

Comment: Do you have `|` in your text content?

Comment: What do you get if you use `df.to_markdown(index=False, tablefmt='pipe')`?

Comment: Still the same, update it to show the error case.

Comment: Even with your changed data, I get the desired result with just `to_markdown(index=False)`. Maybe you need to update your pandas version?

Comment: I also can't reproduce with the latest pandas

Comment: Fond the root cause, I am using emacs org-mode to run the code. Looks like org-mode do some convert base on context. if run it in python from console, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proposed you three methods to do this :

*(My preference is to_markdown method)*

**Source dataframe**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['1','B','C'],
        ['2','E','F'],
        ['3','H','I']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["C1" ,"C2","C3"])
```

**Method 1 : using a specialized function**

Could be done the hard way with a writing function :

```py
def dumpmd(df):
    out = ["|" + "|".join(df.columns) + "|"]
    out.append("|" + "|".join([":-" for _ in df.columns]) + "|")
    out.extend("|" + "|".join(map(str, row)) + "|" for _, row in df.iterrows())
    return "\n".join(out)


print(dumpmd(df))
```

```
|C1|C2|C3|
|:-|:-|:-|
|1|B|C|
|2|E|F|
|3|H|I|
```

**Method 2 : Pandas markdown method**

Use `to_markdown()` Pandas function directly, specifying the appropriate array format for Markdown.

```py
df.to_markdown(tablefmt='pipe')
```

```
'|    |   C1 | C2   | C3   |\n|---:|-----:|:-----|:-----|\n|  0 |    1 | B    | C    |\n|  1 |    2 | E    | F    |\n|  2 |    3 | H    | I    |'
```

Another interesting `tablefmt` parameter is `grid`for instance for rendering :

```py
df.to_markdown(tablefmt='grid')
```

```
'+----+------+------+------+\n|    |   C1 | C2   | C3   |\n+====+======+======+======+\n|  0 |    1 | B    | C    |\n+----+------+------+------+\n|  1 |    2 | E    | F    |\n+----+------+------+------+\n|  2 |    3 | H    | I    |\n+----+------+------+------+'
```

cool grid rendering :

```
+----+------+------+------+
|    |   C1 | C2   | C3   |
+====+======+======+======+
|  0 |    1 | B    | C    |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    2 | E    | F    |
+----+------+------+------+
|  2 |    3 | H    | I    |
+----+------+------+------+
```

**Method 3 : tabulate library**

Use the `tabulate` library to convert the DataFrame to a tabulated string, then convert it to Markdown.

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

# Convert the DataFrame to a tabbed string
tabular_data = tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='pipe')

# Add headers and footers to the table
markdown_data = f"| {' '.join(df.columns)} |\n| {'-' * len(' '.join(df.columns))} |\n{tabular_data}\n"

print(markdown_data)
```

```
'| C1 C2 C3 |\n| -------- |\n|    |   C1 | C2   | C3   |\n|---:|-----:|:-----|:-----|\n|  0 |    1 | B    | C    |\n|  1 |    2 | E    | F    |\n|  2 |    3 | H    | I    |\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate


data = {"spam": [1, 2, 3], "ham": [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
mark_down_df = tabulate(tabular_data=df, tablefmt="github", headers="keys", showindex=False)
print(mark_down_df)
```

Output:

```
|   spam |   ham |
|--------|-------|
|      1 |     4 |
|      2 |     5 |
|      3 |     6 |
```

Comment: `to_markdown` is already using `tabulate`